# Does a lock on class, locks class variables too? - java

Tags: java

I have the below class

```
public class Example{

    public static List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void  addElement(String val){
        synchronized(list){
            list.add(val);
        }
    }

    public static synchronized void printElement(){
        Iterator<String> it = list.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            //print element
        }
    }
}
```

Will the iterator() call in the printElement method throw ConcurrentModificationException? The basic question is if the lock on class object is acquired(as done in printElement method), will it lock the class members/ variables too? please help me with the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does a lock on class, locks class variables too? - java

Your lock is on your *instance*, not your class. And no, it only locks the instance.

> Will the iterator() call in the printElement method throw ConcurrentModificationException?

It will if the code in that method modifies the list during the iteration. But if all of your code in that class *also* synchronizes, **and** you haven't given a reference to that list to anything *outside* your class, then you know that *only* the code in that method is running.

You'd probably be better off, though, synchronizing on the list itself. That way, even if you've given out a reference to the list, assuming all code that uses it synchronizes on it, you'll be safe from concurrent mods:

```
public static void printElement(){
//            ^--- No `synchronized ` here unless you REALLY need it for other reasons

    synchronized (list) {
        Iterator<String> it = list.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            //print element
        }
    }
}
```

If you are giving out references and want to be *really* sure, either use a list returned by [`Collections.synchronizedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29) or something from the [`java.util.concurrent` package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html).

Comment: using two locks might result in some nasty deadlocks, so i would remove the synchronized in the method signature

Comment: @Simiil: *Any* lock can result in a deadlock. :-) But yeah, I've removed it, since it shouldn't be necessary unless there's a reason not shown in the question.

Comment: A lock actually locks nothing. It is used to lock something:)

Answer (score 1):

No, a synchronized method does not lock the object variables, a synchronized method will lock only `this`.

Your code is not thread safe, since you are locking on different objects on addElement and printElement. There is nothing preventing the insertion to occur while iterating the list, if both method are called concurrently.

Answer (score 1):

```
Will the iterator() call in the printElement method throw ConcurrentModificationException?
```

Yes, if addElement and printElement is called by two threads simultaneously.To avoid, ConcurrentModificationException, you could use [CopyOnWriteList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html).

```
if the lock on class object is acquired(as done in printElement method), will it lock the class members/ variables too?
```

synchonized method printElement will aquire the lock of this object.Hence it wont allow another **synchronized method or synchornized(this)** block to be called at the same time, in your class, if there is any.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList` throws `ConcurrentModificationException`  when there will be concurrently modification on the collection or while iterating in case of change in collection structure.

You should better lock the list Object resouce. if list is having getter method to access it outside, so from out side it could able to modify the structure.

```
synchronized (list) {
    Iterator<String> it = list.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        //print element
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You never called `addElement` method, so locking has no effect on this code snippet. While you are iterating over a collection, if you insert/delete element to/from the same collection you get `ConcurrentModificationException`.
From [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html):

> For example, it is not generally permissible for one thread to modify a Collection while another thread is iterating over it. In general, the results of the iteration are undefined under these circumstances. Some Iterator implementations (including those of all the general purpose collection implementations provided by the JRE) may choose to throw this exception if this behavior is detected. Iterators that do this are known as fail-fast iterators, as they fail quickly and cleanly, rather that risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time in the future.